# Blender 2.91.0 Broken Material in Material Mode and Render Mode?

Tags: rendering, materials, gpu

thanks for checking in.

So I was making this in Blender 2.91.0[image: Looks normal in Solid Mode]

But when I go to Material Mode, it becomes like this:[image]

If I rotate the camera while in Material Mode, it becomes this, the background leak into the model or something:[image]

The material is the default material. I made a new one but it's still the same. Changing the properties don't do anything. And this is how it looks like in Render Mode:[image]

And the render result:[image]

I'm using AMD Radeon RX 570 for VGA with driver version 20.12.1, does that mean anything?
I haven't use Blender for texturing since I got this computer, so I don't know when was the last time it worked. Before I changed computer though, it work just fine.
I've tried reinstalling Blender, redownloading, repairing, nothing fix it.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Thank you.
u.u

Comment: The latest AMD drivers are not working properly with blender, rolling back to the previous version seems to work.

Comment: Oke, I'll try. Any specific version that is sure to work?

Comment: The problem versions are Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.11.2 and 20.11.3 - presumably anything other than those should be fine.

Comment: Okay, I'm downloading 20.11.1 now.

Comment: Rolling back to Version 20.11.1 works!
Thanks, guys!
n0n/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the VGA driver.
I rolled back to version 20.11.1 and it worked.
I downloaded here:
https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-570